# Unable To access authorized_keys when logging in through ssh and the user is a sudo user

Tags: linux, perl, scripting

I am connecting to a remote server through SSH abd then switching the user to a sudo user.But then when I am trying to write to the authorized_keys file it is saying...permission denied.

This is what I am able to see as an output::-
"
bash: /home/techm/tmsys/Sap1/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied

"

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't add 'sudo' before the command to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mess up your system,  `cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (or any other way of appending to this file) will work. Make sure you are in the correct directory ! (In this case by using `~`). Becoming root to write to your own authorized_keys is not necessary.

If the user never used `ssh` before then `.ssh` will not exist and you can't write to a file in a directory that doesn't exist, so run ssh to create this dir

If it doesn't work than you have a messed up system and this could be caused by a lot of things:

- The file somehow received incorrect permissions
- The user has been removed
- The .ssh directory has been removed
- ...